# фрагменты listview

Tags: android, listview, android-fragment

Уже вот 3 день не могу понять фрагменты. Вот есть такой лиcтвью 
[www.androidbegin.com](http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/android-jsoup-listview-images-texts-html-tables-tutorial/) как мне его переделать под фрагмент чтобы вызывался при этом методе. Много исходников пересмотрел чет так и не догнал, мне самым примитивным

```
if (drawerItem.getIdentifier() == 1) {
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.frame_container, new Fragment1()).commit();
}
```

Comment: Вопроса самого не видно. В чём конкретно ваша проблема?

Comment: www.androidbegin.com по ссылке пример на активности.  мне нужно перевести это во фрагменты чтобы при getSupportFragmentManager открывался листвю с парсернными страницами

Comment: И в чём же таки проблема-то?  `getSupportFragmentManager()` красным, небось, подчёркивает?

Comment: нет проблема не в этом в примере по ссылки там все на активностях. ссылку

Comment: ну да если ставить фрагмент активити то он красным

Comment: ели просто фрагмент то тогда у самого фрагмента все красное такие методы как getIntent,setContentView,findViewById

Comment: Пишет Wrong 2nd argument type. android.support.v4.app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во фрагментах нет этих методов. Они есть в активити. Пишите так

```
getActivity().method();
```

Comment: Вы наверно не поняли getSupportFragmentManager тут вообще не причем

Comment: То что мне нужно это перевести из активности MainActivity.java во фрагмент то что в ссылке

Comment: @Артем, по ссылке крайне устаревший пример. Во фрагменте нет множества методов активити. Разметку там назначают иначе. Вы же не ожидаете, что вам тут кто-то целиком код по ссылке перепишет? Вам надо зайти с другой стороны - реализовать пример простейшего фрагмента, а уж с ними в черне разобравшись пытаться что-то ещё делать.

Comment: да видел множество примеров и все для меня они сложные я все не могу понять эту передачу данных между фрагментами и активностями. вооще находил примеры через Сериализаци

Comment: @Артем, ну, начните с к-л простейших уроков типа http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/174-urok-104-android-3-fragments-lifecycle.html Не пытайтесь сразу с активити под фрагменты переделывать что-то. Сначала просто "Привет" во фрагменте выведите. И далее усложняйте. В данный момент что вам кто не написал у вас базы знаний не хватит для эффективного понимания.